# Is this possible to retrieve Facebook user name and password in ios Application(Iphone Development)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

Is this possible to retrieve Facebook user name and password in ios Application using OAuth or any other technique.?

Thanks in advance.

With best Regard's

Comment: can you explain it in detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Not Possible.Its Possible in the past but now due to Oauth Its Not Possible.Check Facebook Oauth documents.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the user name provided your ask for the permissions when you add your app. However password --- **There is no way**.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, no, it is not possible to retrieve Facebook passwords using OAuth or any other legal technique.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Simply present a dialog to the user with textfield inputs which allows them to enter the facebook login information.

Also, be sure to have some text explaining exactly why you need this information and what you will be doing with it.

Answer (score -1):

If there was, that would be a huge security flaw.